# CQRS denormalized data query with multiple aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Let's say there's a domain that's similar to Reddit.

Aggregate roots are

```
Board // you can ignore this
  - boardId
Post
  - postId
  - userId
User
  - userId
  - username
```

where each aggregate emits

```
Post
  - PostCreated
User
  - UserCreated
  - UsernameUpdated
```

for the query side, the query will try to fetch a page of posts in a specific board.

Given this, the `denormalized` data should look as below

```
posts: [{
  title: 'some post title',
  body: 'some post body',
  author: 'user123',
}]
```

Now in the denormalised database, I'd create post entry when the `PostCreated` event is received. And the received event holds `userId`.

To populate the `author` field for the read model above with that user ID, I can do either

1. Read username from the existing `denormalized` User data, and save the post read model with the username.

   - This will require updating ALL posts when `UsernameUpdated` event is handled.
2. Create a join column between User and Post. and when query is requested, join the table to populate the `author` field with `username`

Is it so obvious that the second method is the way to do it? The reason why it's confusing me is that the denormalised database feels almost like a giant monolithic database (thinking of adding other aggregate root's events to the read model E.g., Board). Or is denormalized data is just like this?

Comment: That is *not* a domain model, it's a data model with triggers. You don't have to implement things like that, any relational database supports this function set.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam could you elaborate on this, please?

Comment: I'll try my best to fit in a comment. Well, the main reason we write code is that we want some business *behavior* implemented. You don't have any behavior as far as I can tell. You have a data schema, events that get fired on modifications, and queries with some data. You even seem to denormalize the data. That is *exactly* what relational databases are for. You don't need to write any code (well, some SQL maybe) to do this. A *domain* model is a model of your domain, i.e. the *behavior*, not of the database schema.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam what if the aggregates are divided into multiple micro services? since the database is not shared between services, I'd need a query service to denormalize the data..

Comment: Good microservices are essentially like objects, you don't ask for data from them, you tell them what to do. If you have to ask for data, that means either the logic you are trying to execute or the data you're trying to get is likely at the wrong place.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I believe you are right. Hence that's what CQRS is for I believe (separating read model). And my question was about implementing the read model at most..